How to properly type an Http request in a NestJS controller?
I'm configuring a NestJS controller and currently using any as the type for the request. Is there a type I can use to make this a bit more typesafe?
@Controller('endpoint')
@UsePipes(new MongoSanitizePipe())
export class RequestController {
    constructor(private service: Service) {}

    @Post('post')
    async onAction(
        @Body() body: RequestBody,
        @Request() request: any,
    ): Promise<void> {
        return this.service.onAction(body, request.headers);
    }
}

What did you try and what were you expecting?
I couldn't find a type for my HttpRequest.
I expect to properly type it.

The example on NestJs' site uses the Request class from express, and so do I in my company's projects:
import { Controller, Get, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  @Get()
  findAll(@Req() request: Request): string {
    return 'This action returns all cats';
  }
}

If you're using fastify, the package includes a FastifyRequest you can import instead.
